# Replace substring within a match with regex

Tags: regex, r

I'm working with `stringr`, but the solution doesn't have to be.  In the following string I want to replace all the spaces that have a letter to their left and right (i.e. first 2) with underscores.

```
str = 'ab cd ef 29 17 2 3'
```

stringr's `replace_all` don't seem to support substring matching (like `str_match_all` do by enclosing with `(...)`).  And `str_match_all` doesn't replace.  Grateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gsub` function with lookaround based regex.

```
> str = 'ab cd ef 29 17 2 3'
> gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])", "_",str, perl=T)
[1] "ab_cd_ef 29 17 2 3"
```

OR

```
> gsub("[A-Za-z]\\K\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])", "_",str, perl=T)
[1] "ab_cd_ef 29 17 2 3"
```

OR

```
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all('ab cd ef 29 17 2 3', perl('(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])'), '_')
[1] "ab_cd_ef 29 17 2 3"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  For some reason `stringr` can't handle it and returns an _invalid expression_ error for some reason.

Comment: yep, you must need to define the perl option when lookaround based regex is used.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])[ ](?=[a-zA-Z])
```

This should do it for you.Lookbehind will make sure you have letter behind space.

And lookahead will make sure you have a letter ahead of it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/9

Comment: Thanks for the demo vks, that's a handy site.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]])(\\s+)([[:alpha:]])", "\\1_\\3", x)

## "ab_cd_ef 29 17 2 3"
```