# Regular expression to match all combination of following pattern ( mm ' year )

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a match for the following pattern .
I want to find following matches like:

```
May'10 - Jan'11
May ' 10 - Jan ' 11
```

I am able to find the first match somewhat. My regex is :

```
\b([\w]{3,8}'[\s\d]{1,4})
```

Comment: did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/1?

Comment: @ Avinash -  Exactly. But I need to match the hiphen in between them . Like i have to select it as pairs . " May'10 - Jun'11 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b([\w]{3,8}\s*'[\s\d]{1,4})
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/15

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b([\w]{3,8}\s*\'[\s\d]{1,4})', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "May'10 - Jan'11\nMay ' 10 - Jan ' 11"

re.findall(p, test_str)

(\b(?:[\w]{3,8}\s*'[\s\d]{1,4})\s*-\s*(?:[\w]{3,8}\s*'[\s\d]{1,4}))
```

Try this if you want to capture pairs with `-`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/17

Comment: same just you changed `<space>*` in my regex  to `\s*`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's only when its ditto same.Coz SO should be uncluttered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216842/replace-substring-within-a-match-with-regex/28216869#28216869 here too ur original was same as mine but u added later.so its different.Try to understand rather that over reacting

Comment: could you explain the diff between yours and mine?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just add `<space>*` before `'`

```
\b([\w]{3,8} *'[\s\d]{1,4})\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/1)

Update:

```
\b([\w]{3,8} *'[\s\d]{1,4})\b *- *([\w]{3,8} *'[\s\d]{1,4})\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/2)

I added `<space>*` instead of `\s*` because `\s` would match also the line breaks.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b([\w]{3,8} *\'[\s\d]{1,4})\b *- *([\w]{3,8} *\'[\s\d]{1,4})\b', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"May'10 - Jan'11\nMay ' 10 - Jan ' 11"
re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(\w{3,8}\s?'\s?\d{1,4})
```

[This](http://regexr.com/3aao3) explicitely tries to match those spaces around the `'` character. That way you can match digits for the year explicitely (otherwise, your expression would have accepted something like `"May'    "` (four trailing spaces)). And you don’t need to put character classes within character sets.

If you want to match the whole range, you can just duplicate the same and put a hyphen in between:

```
(\w{3,8}\s?'\s?\d{1,4})\s*-\s*(\w{3,8}\s?'\s?\d{1,4})
```

Answer (score 0):

If spaces are the only stoppers here, you can take them out of the picture and then use regex like this...

**Code:**

```
import re 

s1 = """May'10 - Jan'11"""
s2 = """May ' 10 - Jan ' 11"""
pattern = re.compile("""\w{3}\'\d\d\-\w{3}\'\d\d""")
print True if re.match(pattern, s2.replace(" ", "")) else False
print True if re.match(pattern, s2.replace(" ", "")) else False
```

**output:**

```
True
True
```

Hope this helps :)